# Reading a file path from another test project

Tags: c#, .net, path

I have 2 projects as follows:

[image]

I have a test in `UnitTest1.cs` as follows:

```
    public void TestMethod1()
    {            
        string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, $"Models.csproj");         
        var reader = File.ReadAllText(path);
        var a = reader.Contains("PackageReference");
        Assert.IsTrue(a);
    }
```

How do read the file `Models.csproj` from `UnitTest1.cs`? The above code is showing `path` as `\\Models.Tests\\bin\\Debug\\net6.0\\Models.csproj` which is not correct because Models.csproj is not in Debug\net6.0.

Comment: You can use `..` in the path to navigate up to the folder your solution is in then navigate down to your .csproj folder e.g. `Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "..\..\..\Models", "Models.csproj");`

Comment: I tried this and is giving the error: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path '\Models.Tests\Models\Models.csproj'.'

Comment: The path in your error message is absolute (starts with a backslash) and the root is Models.Test, so you don't have the path quite right.

Comment: Is it possible to copy Models.csproj to output directory during compile?

Comment: Remember, when you code is running, it's not running from the source folder, it's running from som `bin` folder. You need to traverse up from there to the solution root and then back down. Also note that if you want to run the tests on the server, you'll need to deploy the csproj file to the serve and do more folder traversal